# MVC ServiceStackController.Execute(requestDto) - why do the filters (like validation) not get fired?

Tags: servicestack

What is the rationale behind not running the filters such as validation for:

```
ServiceStackController.Execute(requestDto)
```

from a MVC controller?

I can understand that if you manually resolve a service from a MVC controller and invoke a method, filters will not get executed.

```
using (var hello = HostContext.
    ResolveService<HelloService>(base.HttpContext))
{
   hello.Get(name);
}
```

But would have expected filters/validation to fire on the `Execute` method...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an internal in-process request that doesn't get validated by the HTTP request pipeline which is used for validating external inbound HTTP Requests.

Comment: So the correct way to make sure request DTOs get validated would be to enable it at the MVC model binding level like this? `FluentValidationModelValidatorProvider.Configure(provider =>
 {
     provider.ValidatorFactory = new FunqValidatorFactory(container);
 });`

Comment: @Ajai up to you how you want to validate it, if you have a typed validator in SS you can access it from `var validator = HostContext.TryResolve<IValidator<Hello>>` and call `validator.Validate(requestDto)` on it to check if the result is valid. This test shows an [example of resolving a validator and manually verifying a Request DTO](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/ce5949bb4524951812e007dcf752d92405deb4b3/tests/ServiceStack.Common.Tests/ValidationTests.cs#L63)